# Should I update .class files in src/main/resources when I update the .java files?

Tags: java, maven, web-applications

My Maven web project looks something like this

```
root dir
- src/main/java
    - abc.java
-src/main/resources
    -abc.class
other folders
```

I am updating abc.java, but I have no idea what to do with abc.class. Should I delete them or let them be and compile the updated project?

Comment: Why is there a `.class` file in `src/main/resources` ? It shouldn't be there in the first place. The compiled code will be in the `target` directory and eventually in the resulting jar file.

Comment: Source java files belong to `src/main/java/<package>/XYZ.java` and in `src/main/resources` only resources belong there; No compiled classes.

Answer (score 0):

I would just let them be and compile the updated project, unless you are going to keep the compiled files somewhere thats not the -src/main/resources
-abc.class
If you compile the new project and put the .class files in the same place it should overwrite your previous files.

If you're putting the new .class files somewhere else I would go ahead and delete the previous ones just as a matter of space.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Can you be more specific and show any examples?
You may find the site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section and this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) checklist useful guidance for asking a good question. It is easier for people to help you if you include the code that you've worked on to solve the problem and ideally provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).